# Is it possible to keep a swap file but disable the auto-recovery mechanism?

Tags: swap-file

I want to have swap files for manual inspection if needed, i.e. I don't want ViM to ask me every time I have a swap file if I want to recover / edit, etc. but I do want to have the option to manually pop up this prompt when I want to (e.g. when I had a shutdown before saving)

Is it possible? Didn't find what I was looking when I read `:help backup`, `:help swap`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vim: (E)dit anyway without prompting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21784/vim-edit-anyway-without-prompting)

Comment: Almost, thanks! The only issue is that even after hitting "e" it sometimes bugs out. I don't want it to even start the prompt

Comment: If I add the autocmd from the answer Biggybi linked then I don't get any prompt nor do I need to press any key; I'm not sure what you mean with "after hitting e" or what prompt you still see @CIsForCookies? I'm using Vim 8.2.4827 by the way (which is very new), so maybe it has to do with your version?

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have already implemented this functionality.

```
set shortmess+=A

au SwapExists * nested call OnSwap() 
function! OnSwap()
    let swap_info = swapinfo(v:swapname)
    echo "Recovery exist " . strftime("%Y %b %d %X",swap_info['mtime']) 
    let v:swapcommand='e'
endfunction
```

The first command doesn't display the message.